# como añadir información a una tabla y que esta acumule las respuestas?

Tags: php, html

intente crear una pagina que añadiera información a una tabla, como una lista de productos con su nombre, código del producto, cantidad del producto y precio unitario.

esta informacion deberia quedar guardada en la tabla, e irse guardando junto a los demas productos introducidos posteriormente.

el problema es que a la hora de guardar informacion no hace nada y da error, intente arreglarlo pero no dio resultado.

este seria el codigo:

```html
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'
    integrity='sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT' crossorigin='anonymous'>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- place navbar here -->
  </header>
  <main>

  <div class='container'>
    <br>
    
        
    

<br>
<br>




<form method=post>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Empresa Pastelito</h3>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <form method = "post">
            <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Ingresar el codigo del producto:</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtcodigo" id="txtcodigo" placeholder="Codigo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Ingresar el nombre del producto:</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtproducto" id="txtproducto" placeholder="Producto">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Ingresar la cantidad del producto:</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtcantidad" id="txtcantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Precio Unitario:</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtprecio" id="txtprecio" placeholder="Precio">
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class='mb-3 row'>
            <div class='offset-sm-4 col-sm-8'>
                <button type='submit' name=ok2 class='btn btn-primary'>Agregar Producto</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class='alert alert-primary' role='alert'>
    <strong>FACTURA</strong> 
</div>
    <table class='table table-dark table-hover'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Codigo</th>
      <th scope='col'>Nombre Producto</th>
      <th scope='col'>Cantidad</th>
      <th scope='col'>Precio Unitario</th>
      <th scope='col'>Total</th>
       
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>


<?php

    $txtcodigo = 0;
    $txtproducto = 0;
    $txtcantidad = 0;
    $txtprecio = 0;
    $txttotal = 0;

if(isset($_POST["ok2"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["productos"])){
        $productos=$_SESSION["productos"];
        $txtcodigo=$_POST["txtcodigo"];
        $txtproducto=$_POST["txtproducto"];
        $txtcantidad=$_POST["txtcantidad"];
        $txtprecio=$_POST["txtprecio"];
        $productos[$txtcantidad * $txtprecio]=$txttotal;
        $_SESSION["productos"]=$productos;
    }else{
        $txtcodigo=$_POST["txtcodigo"];
        $txtproducto=$_POST["txtproducto"];
        $txtcantidad=$_POST["txtcantidad"];
        $txtprecio=$_POST["txtprecio"];
        $productos[$txtcantidad * $txtprecio]=$txttotal;
        $_SESSION["productos"]=$productos;
    }

    
}

?>
         
  </tbody>
</table>


</div>



  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- place footer here -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js'
    integrity='sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  </script>

  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    integrity='sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

intente cambiando las variables pero nada, el ejercicio es solo de php y html con boostrap, no ocupo de una base de datos de ningun tipo

Comment: Es en serio ??? 

Comment: ¿Dónde intentas conectarte a la base de datos y hacer el `INSERT`?